# WebApi OData with NoSQL dynamic properties

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-web-api, odata, ravendb, nosql

We are developing an application with a `NoSql` database (`RavenDb` or `MongoDb`).
This data should be exposed as a WebApi Odata` service.

We use metadata that can be used for queries and will not change. However the other data will be very dynamic in time and the structure that is saved will be different in the future.

We cannot implement a change everytime this data structure changes so we want to have some dynamic data in our `WebApi`.

It is possible in `WebApi OData` map dynamic properties in a dictionary but is this possible to configure this against a NoSql database?

Example for mongo db data

```
{"Readings":[
  {"DeviceID":"1", "ReadingId":"1", "Reading1":"foo"},
  {"DeviceID":"2", "ReadingId":"2", "Reading1":"foo", "Reading2":"bar"},
  {"DeviceID":"3", "ReadingId":"3", "Reading2":"This", "Reading3":"That"}
]}
```

We will need a OData service returning readings with "Reading1", "Reading2", "Reading3". The querying will be performed on "DeviceID" or "ReadingId"

From the devices it could be we will receive "Reading4" and store it flexible. But it will have to be exported next time the OData service is requested.

Comment: What do you mean in "configure this against a NoSql database"? can you give an example in your question?

Comment: @Michael I updated the question